# Convergence of BCH formula for real special orthogonal group/Lie algebra

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

Take the usual real special orthogonal group, represented by real matrices $R$ satisfying $R R^T = I$. It is well known this Lie group has Lie algebra formed of real antisymmetric matrices, matrices A satisfying $A + A^T = 0$ .

Given two real, antisymmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ one can formally construct the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorf-Dynkin formula which states
\begin{align}
    e^A e^B &= e^{Z(A,B)},\\
    Z(A,B) &= A + B + \frac{1}{2}[A,B] + ...
\end{align}
where the dots hide infinitely many nested commutators. It is easy to find examples of matrices, see for example [here, on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence), for which this series does not converge, but I am not aware of examples where both the matrices in question are antisymmetric, i.e. for which we are specifically asking about so(n) and SO(n).

Note that if it is relevant I only particularly care about the even dimensional special orthogonal group/algebra SO(2n), so(2n).

To be as explicit as possible I am asking for any of

1. Necessary / sufficient conditions for convergence of the BCH formula for matrices in so(2n)
2. An example of a pair of so(2n) matrices for which BCH does not converge
3. (this is probably hard) some error bounds of the form "if I take terms up to k nested commutators in the BCH expansion the difference in norm between the matrix I compute and a true logarithm of $e^A e^B$ is less than some function of k"

Note that without loss of generality you can choose one of the matrices (say A) to be of the form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & \lambda\\-\lambda & 0\end{pmatrix} \oplus 0,
\end{align}
where $0$ is a $2(n-1) \times 2(n-1)$ dimensional zero-matrix and $\oplus$ is the direct sum.

Edit: Note I have asked a related, although not identical question on mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412020/is-the-group-law-for-so2n-r-encoded-in-so2n-r).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your WLOG comment - why can we choose $A$ to be of that form?

Comment: @runway44 Essentially because I only care about computing stuff in practice. If A is not of that form I can first block diagonalise $A = R D R^T$, i.e. find some element $R$ of SO(2n) such that $D$ is block diagonal with $2\times 2$  blocks, then $\exp(A) = R \exp(D) R^T$, then $\exp(A) \exp(B) =  R \exp(D) R^T \exp(B) =  R \exp(D) (R^T \exp(B) R) R^T = R \exp(D) \exp(R^T B R) R^T$, then I "feed" the $2\times 2$ blocks of $D$ into the other exponential one by one to get $C$ (this is the bit I don't know how to do), then I can compute $R \exp(C) R^T =  \exp(R C R^T)$.

Comment: @runway44 C is an antisymmetric matrix such that $\exp(D) \exp(R^T B R) = \exp(C)$, such a matrix exists, since the exponential map is surjective for so(n), and I *hope* it is the sum of the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorf series (at least sometimes). Edit, I should have used the notation I used in the main post in which case $C = Z(D, R^T B R)$ for cases where BCH converges.

Comment: I think the key here is that the special orthogonal group is compact and connected and thus the exponential map is surjective. Thus any element can be written as $\exp(Z)$. This $Z$ of course might not be the one you are looking as a limit of the BCH formula for but it strongly suggests to me that they might always converge to such a $Z$.

Comment: @Callum Of course if there were elements of $\mathrm{SO}$ which could not be expressed as the exponential of an element of $\mathfrak{so}$ then this would definitely not work. Sadly this is only a necessary and not (as far as I know) a sufficient condition.